# Issue when finding element from a zipped list will automatic empty the zipped list

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to search an typed item from QTlistwidget, and when selected it will then search again to see if exist from the ziped list.

However, the first time running it will able to find the match. The second time i select, the zip_cmsdata will return me an empty list
For example:
1st time search "Hello", and then selected "Hello" from the Qtlistwdiget
output:

```
item click
[('Hello', 1, 'US', None)]
```

If i click (select) Hello from the QTlistwdiget again, or search other items. I will get the following output

```
item click
[]
```

I am guessing the cmsdata were only added once, so the second time it got cleared. If this is true, how can i solve it?

Please find my code below:

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from re import A
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QStackedWidget, QWidget, QTabWidget, QTableView, QListView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel
import requests
import images
import json

cmsdata = []
cmsdisplayname = []
cid = []
cmscountry = []
parentId = []
zip_cmsdata = []
class PerfectConsoleSearch(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PerfectConsoleSearch, self).__init__()
        loadUi("pfsearch.ui",self)
        with open('cmsdata.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            global cmsdata
            cmsdata = data
            #print(data)
        #print(cmsdata)
        #print(type(cmsdata))
        #self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.gotologin)
        #self.cms_display_list.setStringList(self.cmsdata)
        #self.cms_display_list.setModel(main.cmsdata)
        self.load_cmslist()
        print(self.customer_searchbar.text())
        self.customer_searchbar.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.Search(self.customer_searchbar.text()))
        self.cms_display_list.itemClicked.connect(self.show_select_item)

    def load_cmslist(self):
        n = 0
        a=[]
        #print(cmsdata['customerList'][0]['displayName'])
        while n < len(cmsdata['customerList']):         
            #print(cmsdata['customerList'][n]['displayName'])
            cmsdisplay_name = cmsdata['customerList'][n]['displayName']
            cms_cid = cmsdata['customerList'][n]['cid']
            cms_country = cmsdata['customerList'][n]['country']
            cms_parentId = cmsdata['customerList'][n]['parentId']
            a.append(cmsdisplay_name)
            global cmsdisplayname, cid, cmscountry, parentId
            cmsdisplayname.append(cmsdisplay_name)
            cid.append(cms_cid)
            cmscountry.append(cms_country)
            parentId.append(cms_parentId)
            self.cms_hidden_list.addItem(str(cmsdisplay_name))
            n=n+1
    global zip_cmsdata
    zip_cmsdata = zip(cmsdisplayname,cid,cmscountry,parentId)
    
    def Search(self, text):
        #print(text)
        #print(cmsdisplayname)
        #print(self.cms_display_list.count)
        self.cms_display_list.clear()
        items = self.cms_hidden_list.findItems(text, QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchContains)
        #print(items)
        #print(type(items))
        for i in items:
            #print(i.text())
            self.cms_display_list.addItem(i.text())

    
    def show_select_item(self):
        print('item click')
        item = self.cms_display_list.selectedItems()[0]
        print(item.text())
        #self.label.setText(text_0 + item.text())
        #Find account info
        print([i for i in zip_cmsdata if item.text() in i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zip object is an iterable, which means that it can only be iterated over once. Since it is a global, it is never renewed and returns nothing.

```
a = [i for i in range(0,10)]
b = [i for i in range(20,30)]
Z = zip(a,b)
print("first run")
for i in Z:
    print(i)
print("second run")
for i in Z:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
first run
(0, 20)
(1, 21)
(2, 22)
(3, 23)
(4, 24)
(5, 25)
(6, 26)
(7, 27)
(8, 28)
(9, 29)
second run
```

You can fix this by regenerating your zip object:

```
a = [i for i in range(0,10)]
b = [i for i in range(20,30)]

print("first run")
Z = zip(a,b)
for i in Z:
    print(i)

print("second run")
Z = zip(a,b)
for i in Z:
    print(i)
```

Ouput:

```
first run
(0, 20)
(1, 21)
(2, 22)
(3, 23)
(4, 24)
(5, 25)
(6, 26)
(7, 27)
(8, 28)
(9, 29)
second run
(0, 20)
(1, 21)
(2, 22)
(3, 23)
(4, 24)
(5, 25)
(6, 26)
(7, 27)
(8, 28)
(9, 29)
```

Comment: didnt know can be only iterate  once, renewing it did solve my issue! thx